# rotate image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I'm trying to flip an image in a Yahoo! Widget. They don't support CSS `transform`, an HTML DOM, canvas or WebGL.

How can I flip an image using JavaScript, without access to any APIs those technologies would provide?

Comment: I've tried to edit this question for clarity. I'm assuming that the original "now chance" was a typo for "no chance".

Comment: thanks for all of your replies. But the problem is there is no support for DOM, canvas. Then How I can achieve this....?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should take a look at http://raphaeljs.com/.

> Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

Comment: Quoting support for a collection of browsers that aren't Yahoo! Widgets when the question specifically states that is the target platform isn't too useful (unless accompanied by a reference that shows Y!Ws using the same engine as one of those browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Give raphael.js a whirl, it can do this sort of thing. Think it uses canvas.

There's a demo of it doing rotation: http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html